# Gridview/Listview (item limit area)

Tags: android, listview, gridview, limit

I have 04 itens in GridView, after Grid I have a empty space and with others resolutions, the empty space is bigger. (I have other Grid and Listviews with same problem).

How can I solve this?

XML1:

```
    <GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridSkills"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tableRowSpecialization"
    android:numColumns="1"
    android:smoothScrollbar="true"
    android:listSelector="@null">
</GridView>
```

XML2:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/bg_list_item_wrap" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:paddingLeft="7dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:src="@drawable/mage_icon">
 </ImageView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/title"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
    android:paddingTop="4dp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="22sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/description"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:paddingRight="1dp"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:textSize="12sp"/>
```

Image: http://s9.postimg.org/8pl76m19b/Untitled_1.jpg

Answer (score 0):

the width & height  for the Relative layot should be fill_parent :  try :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/bg_list_item_wrap" >

//
```